# Typescript ESLint, is it possible null check in global function and it pass ESLint

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, eslint

```
  const isNotNullNumber = (e: number | undefined) => {
    if (e !== null && e !== undefined && e !== 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };

  //pass eslint
  if (promotionBadgeData?.discountPercent) {
    icon1 = <Text>{`${promotionBadgeData?.discountPercent}%\nOff`}</Text>;
  }

  //pass eslint
  if (
    promotionBadgeData?.discountPercent !== null &&
    promotionBadgeData?.discountPercent !== undefined &&
    promotionBadgeData?.discountPercent !== 0
  ) {
    icon1 = <Text>{`${promotionBadgeData?.discountPercent}%\nOff`}</Text>;
  }

  //fail eslint
  if (isNotNullNumber(promotionBadgeData?.discountPercent)) {
    icon1 = <Text>{`${promotionBadgeData?.discountPercent}%\nOff`}</Text>;
  }
```

in this case, use the global function to null check and it will show

`ESLint: Invalid type "number | undefined" of template literal expression.(@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions)`

so, is it possible use the global function to null check and pass the ESLint?

[screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpPZL.png)

Comment: [User-defined type guards.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) Please post your code as code-formatted text in the question, instead of as a screenshot.

Comment: Note: for `number | undefined`, this function is nearly equivalent to `if (promotionBadgeData?.discountPercent)` (the only other falsy number is NaN).

Comment: got it, but can I use the global function to check it? because I have some variables that need to be check with the same logic eg null check & variable > 10, I don't want to have a lot of the same if else case in my program.